# Does "general information and use only" means that I can use for commercial purpose?

Tags: copyright

The following text shows the terms and conditions of this site: https://alltransistors.com/terms.php

> Welcome to our website. If you continue to browse and use this
>   website, you are agreeing to comply with and be bound by the following
>   terms and conditions of use, which together with our privacy policy
>   govern alltransistors.com's relationship with you in relation to this
>   website. If you disagree with any part of these terms and conditions,
>   please do not use our website.
>
> The term 'alltransistors.com' or 'us' or 'we' refers to the owner of
>   the website. The term 'you' refers to the user or viewer of our
>   website.
>
> The use of this website is subject to the following terms of use:
>
> **The content of the pages of this website is for your general
>   information and use only.** It is subject to change without notice.
>
> This website uses cookies to monitor browsing preferences. If you do
>   allow cookies to be used, the following personal information may be
>   stored by us for use by third parties: Tracking cookies.
>
> Neither we nor any third parties provide any warranty or guarantee as
>   to the accuracy, timeliness, performance, completeness or suitability
>   of the information and materials found or offered on this website for
>   any particular purpose. You acknowledge that such information and
>   materials may contain inaccuracies or errors and we expressly exclude
>   liability for any such inaccuracies or errors to the fullest extent
>   permitted by law.
>
> **Your use of any information or materials on this website is entirely
>   at your own risk, for which we shall not be liable. It shall be your
>   own responsibility to ensure that any products, services or
>   information available through this website meet your specific
>   requirements.**
>
> All trade marks reproduced in this website which are not the property
>   of, or licensed to, the operator are acknowledged on the website.
>
> **Unauthorised use of this website may give rise to a claim for damages
>   and/or be a criminal offence.**
>
> From time to time this website may also include links to other
>   websites. These links are provided for your convenience to provide
>   further information. They do not signify that we endorse the
>   website(s). We have no responsibility for the content of the linked
>   website(s).

According to the `"The content of the pages of this website is for your general
 information and use only"` statement, can I use the content of this site for commercial purpose?

I want to create an app (by using the content of this site), and sell it.

They don't answer my emails for such permission.

Answer (score 3):

### No

You are limited to “**your** ... use only”. You are not given permission to make this available for 3rd parties either commercially or for free.